# Get Map Bounds Using Android Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I determine if a geopoint is displayed in currently viewable area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248510/how-can-i-determine-if-a-geopoint-is-displayed-in-currently-viewable-area)

I was wondering if there was any way (I'm somewhat a newbie at Java) to get the MapBounds of a Google MapView on Android.

Just to clarify, here's what I'd like to do.

Calculate the maximum and minimum long and lat whenever the map is moved, or zoomed and display those values in a Toast.

Is there any possible way to do this -- or am I in over my head?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should be able to use

```
mapView.getLatitudeSpan();
mapView.getLongitudeSpan();
```

in combination with

```
mapView.getMapCenter();
```

to figure out the visible area.

But I have noticed some users had issues with it.

[Mapview getLatitudeSpan and getLongitudeSpan not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2667386/mapview-getlatitudespan-and-getlongitudespan-not-working)

You should check the android developer group as well maybe.

Comment: Thanks, with those two commands and the point that I got from the locationManager service, things are working pretty well.

Comment: This answer gives the clue I was missing after reading yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3413194/how-to-load-markers-dynamically-for-current-position-in-android-google-maps/3413311#3413311

Comment: mapView.getMapCenter() instead of getCenter()

Comment: @RomainPiel For newer SDKs you're right, at the time of writing, getCenter() was the only method around though afaik (SDK 8). Thanks for the info.

Comment: If you want the complete code here is it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13674810/450148