# Incorrect values of Bounding Box after rotated the MapView

Tags: android, osmdroid

I use the `getProjection().getBoundingBox()` to receive the coordinates of the center of the map and coordinates of the one of the corners of the map. I noticed that when I scroll the maps the `getBoundingBox()` returns valid values but what I want is to get coordinates after the  activity is rotated without scrolling the map `getBoundingBox()` returns zeros.

How to handle with this problem?

Thanks for advance.

Comment: How are you rotating the maps? Are you calling setRotation() or setMapOrientation() on the MapView?

Comment: The MapView rotates automatically when I rotate the device.

Comment: Setting the setRotation() or setMapOrientation() does not affect the returning correct values by setBoundingBox methods. Still it returns zeros

Comment: The solution for my problem is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2667871/1485601