# Display overlay Item which falls into current visible area Google Map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps

I have lots of data to display on the Google Map but what I want is only put those elements which falls into current visible space on the Google Map.
How to do this? Provide some useful tutorial links.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be useful to see some of your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming by 'lots of data' you mean some markers to plot.  Get the current map bounds.  As you're looping over your data, adding markers, use bounds.contains() to see if the marker's position would be visible.  If so, add it to the map.

Comment: thanks for the answer checking it.found the answer with code [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248510/how-can-i-determine-if-a-geopoint-is-displayed-in-currently-viewable-area)

Answer (score 3):

Please check this link : https://github.com/ketankpatel/android/tree/master/PinDropAnimation

It drops pin in the visible area.

Snippet is here:

```
private void putEventOverlay() {

        if (mapData.getZoomLevel() < 3) {
            mapData.getController().setZoom(3);

        }
        final MyLocationOverlay myLocationOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay(HomeActivity.this, mapData);
        mapData.getOverlays().add(myLocationOverlay);
        myLocationOverlay.enableMyLocation();

        GeoPoint center = mapData.getMapCenter();
        Integer latspan = mapData.getLatitudeSpan();
        Integer lonspan = mapData.getLongitudeSpan();
        Integer maxLat = center.getLatitudeE6() + (latspan / 2);
        Integer maxLon = center.getLongitudeE6() + (lonspan / 2);
        Integer minLat = center.getLatitudeE6() - (latspan / 2);
        Integer minLon = center.getLongitudeE6() - (lonspan / 2);

        double maxLatitude, minLatitude, maxLongitude, minLongitude;

        maxLatitude = maxLat / 1E6;
        minLatitude = minLat / 1E6;
        maxLongitude = maxLon / 1E6;
        minLongitude = minLon / 1E6;

        Drawable marker = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        EventDetailModel tempDetailModel = null;
        ArrayList<EventDetailModel> tempDetailList = dbHelper.getMapSortedEventData(minLatitude, maxLatitude, minLongitude,maxLongitude);

        if (tempDetailList.size() != 0) {
            mapData.getOverlays().clear();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < tempDetailList.size(); i++) {
            tempDetailModel = (EventDetailModel) tempDetailList.get(i);
            MapItemizedOverlay itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(marker);
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(HomeActivity.this, tempDetailModel);
            mapData.getOverlays().add(itemizedOverlay);
        }

        mapData.invalidate();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        if (ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {

            putEventOverlay();
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    }
```

- Vandit