# Android: How to check visibility of OverlayItems on MapView

Tags: android, android-mapview, visibility, overlayitem

Is there a way to check the visibility of an OverlayItem? So all I want to know is, if a overlay Item is shown on the map or already outside of the projection.

I'm afraid using the bounding box method of my original object which is represented by the overlay is a bit slow and since the MapView is doing this anyway...
(like here[How can I determine if a geopoint is displayed in currently viewable area?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248510/how-can-i-determine-if-a-geopoint-is-displayed-in-currently-viewable-area))

Hopefully someone knows an answer.

Regards,
 Tobias

Comment: This is a slow process however you do it. You need to go through ALL items and check if they are within the area of the screen.

Comment: So there is no way to get the information the MapView should have somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best approach is the one you're already using (linking to). Perhaps you could look into ways to optimize the speed of it or reduce the amount of overlays you're using?