# draw over 4K polylines in android google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, performance

I'm developing right now an application for Android devices. The main functionality is to draw polylines on map to show what is the traffic in the city on each street. Unfortunately when I draw around 3K polylines - the number is reduced according to the screen size and zoom level - my map gets incredibly slow... I do not mention the time of drawing all of the lines.

Maybe you know more efficient way to mark streets or draw lines on a map?

I was also thinking about switching to OSM but I never used it and I don't know how efficient it is.

I debug app on Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 and App uses Map API v2

My code to draw polylines:

```
Polyline line;
List<Float> coordinatesStart;
List<Float> coordinatesEnd;
LatLng start;
LatLng end;
List<List<Float>> coordinates;
int polylinesNumber = 0;
for(Features ftr : features){
    coordinates = ftr.geometry.coordinates;

    for(int i = 0; i<coordinates.size()-1; i++){

            coordinatesStart = coordinates.get(i);
            coordinatesEnd = coordinates.get(i+1);
            start = new LatLng(coordinatesStart.get(1), coordinatesStart.get(0));
            end = new LatLng(coordinatesEnd.get(1), coordinatesEnd.get(0));
            line = map.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
             .add(start, end)
             .width(3)
             .color(0x7F0000FF)); //semi-transparent blue
            polylinesNumber++;

    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Comment: Try using less wasteful data structures, e.g. List<List<Float>> could be List<float[]>. And try to shared objects where possible (does every line need its own PolylineOptions()? shouldn't one for all suffice?).

Comment: As I assume this solution will improve only the time of drawing. What about responsiveness of map when the lines are already drawn? Unfortunately for each line I will choose one of 3 colors so that's why I need PolylineOptions()...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you check if the polyline that you draw is even visible to the user on the screen? If not, that would be my first idea. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2248510/how-can-i-determine-if-a-geopoint-is-displayed-in-currently-viewable-area) could be of help for that.

Comment: Polylines are visible on the screen it's not the problem.

Comment: I wonder what you do with thousends of polylines then, the user won't be able to do anything with that much information. Perhaps you could post a screenshot of your map 'in action'?

Comment: The thing is that when I want to mark the streets i have to chop lines into small pieces to make curves and so on, that's why there are so many elements. 
Here you can see the working web application:
[link](http://imageshack.us/f/194/screenshot2013052710544.png/)
and here is mine on Android:
[link](http://imageshack.us/f/547/screenshot2013052710544.png/)
You can see that only few streets are marked and its already around 3000 lines

Comment: I don't think you need thousands of polylines to properly display those streets. I would try to drastically reduce the precision of the streets, eg. if you have a street that consists of 500 points (and polylines between them), just take only every 5th or 10th point, then draw the polylines. You can still redraw the street more precise when the user zooms in.

Comment: Thank you guys for answers. I thinking about improving my algorithm as you suggested but I wanted to ask maybe somebody had different idea to approach this problem. Once again thank you your help!

Answer (score 5):

### Great optimization here:

Your main error is that **you use** `new PolyLineOptions` **instance for each and every line you draw to the maps.** This is make the drawing terribly slow.

The solution would be:

Only use one instance of polyline options and use only the `.add(LatLng)` function inside the loops.

```
    //MAGIC #1 here
    //You make only ONE instance of polylineOptions.
    //Setting width and color, points for the segments added later inside the loops.
    PolylineOptions myPolylineOptionsInstance = new PolylineOptions()
            .width(3)
            .color(0x7F0000FF);

    for (Features ftr : features) {
        coordinates = ftr.geometry.coordinates;

        for (int i = 0; i < coordinates.size(); i++) {

            coordinatesStart = coordinates.get(i);
            start = new LatLng(coordinatesStart.get(1), coordinatesStart.get(0));

            //MAGIC #2 here
            //Adding the actual point to the polyline instance.
            myPolylineOptionsInstance.add(start);

            polylinesNumber++;
        }
    }

    //MAGIC #3 here
    //Drawing, simply only once.
    line = map.addPolyline(myPolylineOptionsInstance);
```

Attention:

If you would like to have different colors for different line segmnents/sections you would have to use multiple polyline options, because polyline option could have only 1 color. But the method would be the same: Use as few polylineOptions as you can.

Comment: That completely solved my problem. Before it took ~20 seconds to draw my large polyLine, now it is way below a second.

Comment: the polylines disappear when the zoom is changed. Any fixes?

Comment: @Rishabh Srivastava

I guess you removing those accidentally?

Answer (score 2):

This might be of help as well:

http://discgolfsoftware.wordpress.com/2012/12/06/hiding-and-showing-on-screen-markers-with-google-maps-android-api-v2/

Answer (score 2):

I want to chime in on this because I didn't find this answer complete. If you zoom out you're going to still have a ton of individual polylines on screen and the UI thread will grind to a halt. I solved this problem using a custom `TileProvider` and a spherical mercator projection of my `LatLng` points to screen pixels. The idea came from the [map-utils-library](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/), which has most of the needed tools to write a canvas to a tile (and a lot of other niceities, too).

I've written an example [ComplexTileOverlays](https://github.com/stewjacks/complex-overlay-tiles) from a project I was working on. This includes ways to change alpha and line thickness in the `CustomTileProvider`.

I first load my custom database of polylines into memory using a splashscreen (for this example, it's an open database of bike facilities on the island of Montréal). from there, I draw each line projection on a canvas 256x256 pixel canvas representing one tile. Overall this technique is faster by leaps and bounds if you have a lot of graphical overlays to tie to the map.